# what will be the del operator

Tags: differential-geometry

if the curve in $ x,y,z$ is parameterized as $(r(\gamma )\cos (\theta),r(\gamma ) \sin(\theta ), z(\gamma ))$. 
where the curve in $x,z$ is rotated about $z $ axis 
With $\gamma$ being the arc length. i want to ask how the $\nabla $ operator will change in this case  $\nabla =\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}e_x+\dfrac{\partial }{\partial y}e_y + \dfrac{\partial }{\partial z}e_z$